# Confusion matrix "Can't handle mix of multiclass and unkown"

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

My confusion matrix is showing up an error that I can't understand.
I want a confusion matrix to show the confusion between two arrays, `y_pred` and `y_test`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pylab as pl

# Code that fills up two numpy arrays, y_test and y_pred with integers

print y_test.shape
print y_pred.shape

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
plt.matshow(cm)
plt.title('Confusion matrix')
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work_asaaki\code\test_samme_46_classes_unconfused.py", line 159, in <module>
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 742, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_clf_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 115, in _check_clf_targets
    "".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Can't handle mix of multiclass and unknown
```

What does the error mean?
When I print out `y_pred.shape` and `y_test.shape`, I get the same shape, (318L). The values of both arrays range between 0 and 29.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I found the answer, it was quite simple.
The problem was that in the code (not shown), I had populated y_pred as a numpy array using `dtype=object`, liked this:

```
y_pred = np.array(pickle.load(file("PATH_TO_FILE")), dtype=object)
```

I removed the `dtype=object` part and it worked fine.